# Why does the integral of $\sin x$ over the interval $[0,\,2\pi]$ not go to 0 in Fourier Analysis?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[Square Wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHuiQ.jpg)

[Formula for ak, bk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsYwD.png)

As the square wave function is odd, I know that there will be no terms $a_k$.

So what I'm left with finding is $b_k$.

As $x(t)$ will equal $3$ or $-3$, all I really have to integrate is $\sin x$ over the interval of $[0,\, 2\pi]$. My question is why can I take the integral as equal to double the positive area instead of it just equaling $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product of an odd function, $x(t)$, with another odd function, $\sin(w t)$, is an even function. In particular, if $y(t)=x(t) \sin(w t)$ then $y(-t)=x(-t) \sin(-w t) = (-x(t))(-\sin(w t))= y(t)$. Consequently, $$\int_{-a}^{a} y(t) dt= \int_{-a}^{0} y(t) dt + \int_{0}^{a} y(t) dt = -\int_{a}^{0} y(\xi) d\xi + \int_{0}^{a} y(t) dt = 2\int_0^{a} y(t) dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I should have searched the internet more thoroughly. [How does knowing a function as even or odd help in integration ??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438691/how-does-knowing-a-function-as-even-or-odd-help-in-integration) answers my question (after referencing @Math Lover's answer).